# Moving files with python using a list .txt

Tags: python

I want to move files from one directory to another from a .txt file containing the names of the files to be moved, the script must first browse the directory and if it finds the file it moves it to the new directory. Where to start? I've managed to do this for a file list but I'd like to do it directly via the .txt file without rewriting the names of the files to be moved

```
import shutil, os
files = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt', 'file4.txt']
for file in files:
shutil.move(file, 'destination_directory')
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files shows you how to read and write files. Searching for how to read lines of a text file into a list in Python is also a good option.

Comment: " I'd like to do it directly via the .txt file without rewriting the names of the files to be moved" I can't understand what this means.

Comment: provide only the path of the .txt file containing the file name to be moved. The script will then have to go through this list to find the files, once found it will move them

Comment: is your question about how to read a text file into a list then? If so then could you update your question?

Comment: read the .txt list and from this list find the files in the directory and move them

Answer (score 1):

As I know, U cant move your files with .txt

> Just move your file_path

You can use my code below.
I have double checked and it work on my side.

Sorry for my poor English Skill :)

```
import os
import shutil
from pathlib import Path


def create_directory(dir_name: str):
    """To create directory before create files: txt, csv..."""
    system_path = os.getcwd()
    dir_path = os.path.join(system_path, dir_name)

    try:
        os.makedirs(dir_path, exist_ok=True)
    except OSError as error:
        print("Directory '%s' can not be created" % dir_name)

    return dir_path


def create_files(dir_path: str, file_name: str):
    """Function for creating files"""
    file_path = dir_path + fr"\{file_name}"

    with open(file_path, "w") as open_file:
        if Path(file_path).is_file():
            print(f'File: {file_name} created successfully')
        else:
            print(f'File: {file_name} does not exist')

    open_file.close()  # Need to close.
    return file_path


def main():
    # Step 1: Creating file1.txt, file2.txt, file3.txt, file4.txt
    file_one = create_files(create_directory("file1_dir"), 'file1.txt')
    file_two = create_files(create_directory("file2_dir"), 'file2.txt')
    file_three = create_files(create_directory("file3_dir"), 'file3.txt')
    file_four = create_files(create_directory("file4_dir"), 'file4.txt')

    # Step 2: Creating destination_directory:
    destination_dir = create_directory('destination_directory')

    files = [file_one, file_two, file_three, file_four]

    # Step 3: Moving Your Files:
    for file in files:
        shutil.move(file, destination_dir)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```